# CGAL Weighted_pointC2 for Epeck kernel

Tags: c++, cgal

I have a project where `CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel` is used for  `CGAL::Arrangement_with_history_2`. Now there is a task to add a property to each point which should not affect point operations (just extra data providing). I read tutorial from [CGAL Extensible Kernel guide](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/index.html#sectionextensiblekernel), but it looks strange and difficult to override all geometric operations and classes for all geometric traits. Also, it is not very clear how to support lazy operations and Interval arithmetic, how is it works in `CGAL::Epeck`.

Edit: Vertex record in the DCEL can't be used because not every point has DCEL vertex (CGAL vertices is the edge ends, but the edges have intermediate points |Points| >= |Vertices|)

1. I found `Weighted_point_2.h`, which define `Weighted_pointC2` class with scalar field. Can this type of point be used for `CGAL::Epeck` kernel? Maybe there is a example?
2. Maybe there is an example code where the code for creating a Epeck-like kernel for a custom point?

Comment: Carefully read the "Extensible Kernel" section in the manual page of the "2D and 3D Linear Geometry Kernel". You definitely do not need to o override all geometric operations. In your case you only need to override the construct_point_2_object() function and, naturally, the Point_2 type. Alternatively, consider extending the Vertex record in the DCEL.

Comment: Thanks! Vertex records can't be used, I updated question

Comment: ok, so follow the example in Extensible Kernel"...